# ASP.net dropdownlist load on demand

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if anyone know or come across any tutorial or howto on loading data to the dropdownlist on demand like the rad control by telerik where you can initially load say 10 items to the dropdownlist control then at the very bottom of the dropdown there is a continue or load the next 10 items, click on it then the control will load the next 10 items...etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the AJAX control toolkit - especially the [CascadingDropDown Sample](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx). I am sure you could customize the handler to limit the return set and expand on demand.